# Can I apply the same formula in excel?

Tags: office-hub

In windows or anywhere else I can copy/paste. Is there any way to Apply the same formula (automatically adjusting for new location like normal excel) on the phone client?

if I had E3 `=B3/B2-1` and copied it to E4 i'd get `=B4/B3-1`

Answer (score 1):

Excel lets you copy paste the contents of the cell, but I can't find a way to make it auto adjust the formula. This makes sense as you are copying the contents of the cell, not the cell itself.

Sorry, but as of now you are out of luck.